# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger in linux

Tags: java

This is my simple program

First of all , log4j is present under WEB-INF/lib directory .

```
package com.util;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class TestCron {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestCron.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("sysout sattement for sample ");
        logger.error("This should appear inside dealer logs");
    }
}
```

I have got a script which I am trying to run manually in Linux.

```
 #!/bin/bash 
cd /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/Test/WEB-INF/classes/
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_67 
CLASSPATH=/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/Test/WEB-INF/lib/*: .
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlogfile=/root/MyAppLogs/dealer/app.log -cp . $CLASSPATH com.util.TestCron
```

I am getting the following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue ?

**Edited part**

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/OMS/WEB-INF/classes/
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_67 
CLASSPATH=/usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/OMS/WEB-INF/lib/*: .
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlogfile=/root/OrientAppLogs/dealer/app.log -cp .:$CLASSPATH com.util.TestCron
```

Comment: it seems, your $classpath is not included into -cp parameter value because it uses a semicolon as separator. it could look like `-cp .;$CLASSPATH` or similar

Comment: when i do that i am getting all java options .

Comment: did you do it as `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dlogfile=/root/MyAppLogs/dealer/app.log -cp .;$CLASSPATH com.util.TestCron`?

Answer (score 1):

In your invocation I see `-cp . $CLASSPATH`. File separator used in classpath is `:` on linux environment, therefore only current directory is included in the classpath.

I think you need to change it to `-cp .:$CLASSPATH`

Comment: still the same exception , please see the edited part in my question where i included the updated script as per your comments.

Comment: You can't use `*` in classpath. I suggest you find an introductory text on setting up classpath and make sure you understand it.